# Issue working with animating an svg in velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, svg, velocity.js

I am working with an svg animation using the velocity.js plug in on a loop. The issue I'm having is that I am using the animation on a loop and when the user clicks a button on the page I need the loop to stop and restart at the beginning of the function because I need it to go through the variables I have set at the beginning again. There are two svg paths that rotate scale and color as well. I have variables for seeing if the user is using IE as the scale is rendering differently in IE for me in velocity.js for some reason as well as for a color change in the svg fill. This is what I have so far that is not working properly, any help would be appreciated:

```
function start() {

$star1 = $("#path1");
$star2 = $("#path2");
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
var detectIEregexp = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/ //test for MSIE x.x
}
else {// if no "MSIE" string in userAgent
var detectIEregexp = /Trident.*rv[ :]*(\d+\.\d+)/ //test for rv:x.x or rv x.x where Trident string exists
}

if (detectIEregexp.test(navigator.userAgent)){ //if some form of IE
var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
}

if   ( (ieversion>=9)&&($('#pageframe').hasClass('white')) ) { 
$('#path1, #path2').css('fill','#FFFFFF');
var fill_1 = "#FFFFFF";
var fill_2 = "#FFFFFF";
var scale_1 = "[1.04]";
var scale_2 = "[1.03]"; 
}
else if  ( (ieversion>=9)&&(!$('#pageframe').hasClass('white')) ) { 
$('#path1').css('fill','#F7A800'); 
$('#path2').css('fill','##FFCF55');
var fill_1 = "#FFCF55";
var fill_2 = "#F7A800";
var scale_1 = "[1.04]";
var scale_2 = "[1.03]"; 
}
else if ( !(ieversion>=9)&&($('#pageframe').hasClass('white')) ) {
$('#path1, #path2').css('fill','#FFFFFF');
var fill_1 = "#FFFFFF";
var fill_2 = "#FFFFFF";
var scale_1 = "[1.10]";
var scale_2 = "[1.05]"; 
}
else {
$('#path1').css('fill','#F7A800'); 
$('#path2').css('fill','##FFCF55');
var fill_1 = "#F7A800";
var fill_2 = "#FFCF55";
var scale_1 = "[1.10]";
var scale_2 = "[1.05]"; 
} 

$star2.velocity({ 

fill: fill_1,
scale: scale_1
},
{ 
duration: 1200,
delay: 0,
easing: "ease-in-out",
complete: start, 
loop: true
})
.velocity("reverse");

$star1.velocity({ 
fill: fill_2,
scale: scale_2 
}, 
{ 
duration: 1200,
delay: 0,
easing: "ease-in-out",
complete: start, 
loop: true
})
.velocity("reverse");
}
}
$("#next_arrow").click(function() {    
$star1.velocity("stop", true);
$star2.velocity("stop", true);
start();
});

start();
```

Comment: had you tried to use [finish](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#finish) instead of stop?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: no luck with finish either :(